# How to detect changes of @Input() binding with user defined type in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

Following is the example code , for what i am doing.

Model Component

```
//app.models.ts
export class Employee{
 Name:string;
 Salary:number;
}
```

Root Component

```
//app.component.ts 
import { Component } from '@angular/core';   
import { Employee } from './app.models.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="emp.Name"><hello [employee]="emp"></hello>'
})
export class AppComponent  {
  emp:Employee;
  constructor(){
    this.emp=new Employee();
    this.emp.Name="Neeraj";
  }      
}
```

Child Component

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from './app.models.ts';
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>{{displayName}}</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})

export class HelloComponent implements OnChanges  {
  @Input() employee: Employee;
  displayName:string;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log('Life cycle hook method called.');
        this.displayName='Hello, '+this.employee.Name;
        }
}
```

Textbox text changes are not being detecting in the child component.

**[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3vvuha?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the inputs changes with ngOnChanges (https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

```
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  prop: number;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```

EDIT
Your value emp is not modified when the property name is changed, so no changes are detected in the child component. What you can do is pass only the property

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="emp.Name"><hello [name]="emp.Name"></hello>'  
})
export class AppComponent  {
  emp:Employee;
  constructor(){
    this.emp=new Employee();
    this.emp.Name="Neeraj";
  }

}
```

And

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>{{displayName}}</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})

export class HelloComponent implements OnChanges  {
  @Input() name: String;
  displayName:string;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log('Life cycle hook method called.');
        this.displayName='Hello, '+this.name;
        }
}
```

Comment: I want to use my user defined type for input property. Ex- @Input  prop:MyClass;

Comment: What is the user ? where does it come from ? And what is your problem ? 
Edit your question to be clearer

Comment: Hi HMarteau, i have edited my question, now is it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can choose either

- using ngOnChanges
- using getter and setter from typescript

Read out [more here](https://ngdev.space/angular-2-input-property-changes-detection-3ccbf7e366d2)

<kbd>[Working example](https://embed.plnkr.co/XaAWHluIJPD3KSc8ZLtc/)</kbd>